# Unable to connect signal and signal handler in Glade GTK+3

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

Hi i'm working on a project in GTK+ 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I'm trying to use Glade,but when i tried to connect a "toggled" signal of toggle button to a function called kaczka ,after compiling i got this in my console:    `(Gra_w_Statki:11072): Gtk-Warning**:Could not find signal handler 'kaczka. Did you compile with -rdynamic?`

The window and the button render itself and work normally except of that toggling button doesn't change anything. What am i doing wrong ?

This is how i tried to connect toggle button and function [Click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozolq.png)

My Linker Settings are :     `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

And my compiler settings are:      `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`

I'm using Code ::Blocks 13.12 with GCC compiler.

And this is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
void kaczka (GtkToggleButton *tbutton, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *win = NULL;
  GtkBuilder *builder;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


builder=gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "kaczka.glade", NULL);

    win=GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window1"));


gtk_builder_connect_signals( builder, NULL );
g_object_unref( G_OBJECT( builder ) );



  gtk_widget_show_all (win);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [gtk_builder_connect_signals()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals) and [gtk_builder_add_callback_symbol()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-add-callback-symbol) documentation. Basically you need to either

- use `gtk_builder_add_callback_symbol()` on all callbacks before connecting the signals or
- link with gmodule-export-2.0 and use compile flags "-Wl,--export-dynamic" to export even unused symbols.

Comment: great! It worked. I believe it was added in gtk+-3, because using gtk+-2.0 it wasn't necessary call gtk_builder_add_callback_symbol().

Answer (score 3):

You can add more compiler settings with,

`pkg-config --libs --cflags gmodule-2.0`.

If anyone is building the program with meson, just add

`gmoddep = dependency('gmodule-2.0')`

to list of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Add -rdynamic to export the function and make it visible
to the loader.

> > gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o kaczka kaczka.c `pkg-config
>   --libs gtk+-3.0`
>
> > ./kaczka

(kaczka:31686): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler   'on_destroy'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

> > gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o kaczka kaczka.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -rdynamic
>
> > ./kaczka

No warning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and one good person helped me to solve it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68164648/how-to-connect-signals-to-handle-in-gtk-3-0-application-using-glade-ang-geany) you can find an answer from him. Just use `extern "C" {//put your handlers here}` block.