# GTK Glade can't connect signal handlers

Tags: c, gtk

Im on GTK3. I have setup a GUI with glade and following handlers for the toplevel window:

[image: here]

And following main.c :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean on_wnd_delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data){
  g_print ("delete event occurred\n");
  return TRUE;
}

static void on_wnd_destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  GtkBuilder *gtkBuilder;
  GtkWidget  *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  gtkBuilder = gtk_builder_new();

  gtk_builder_add_from_file(gtkBuilder, "gui.glade", NULL);

  window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(gtkBuilder, "wnd"));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, window);

  g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

At compiling I get warnings:

```
main.c:3:13: warning: ‘on_wnd_delete_event’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void on_wnd_delete_event(){
             ^
main.c:8:13: warning: ‘on_wnd_destroy’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void on_wnd_destroy(){
             ^
```

And at running the events defined by me arent called.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `gtk_builder_connect_signals` the callback functions can't be static cause the builder.c file needs access to them. [̣see here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-connect-signals)

It is also neccessary to `gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, NULL);` instead of `gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder, window);` .

Answer (score 0):

You can add callback symbols in this way:

```c
gtk_builder_add_callback_symbol 
        (gtkBuilder,
         "on_wnd_delete_event",
          G_CALLBACK(on_wnd_delete_event));
```

You can also export symbols to become usable, but then you have to change compile flags as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931171/2316442