# unable to connect callback function fron glade in gtk3 c program

Tags: c, callback, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am using learning GTK+ and glade.I want make a program in which when user presses minus button the label number will decrease and if he/she/it presses add button then label number should increase

here is my main.c file:-

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

long a;
char s[20];

void add(short u)
{
    ++a;
    sprintf(s,"%ld",a);
}

void minus(short u)
{
    --a;
    sprintf(s,"%ld",a);
}

int main (int arg , char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&arg,&argv);

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder,"window1.glade",0);

    GtkWidget *win,*num;

    win = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"window1"));
    num = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"label1"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder,0);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(num),s);

    gtk_widget_show_all(win);

    gtk_main();
}
```

Whenever I ran this program I get following in termainal:-

$

```
 ./a.out 

(a.out:3796): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'minus'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

(a.out:3796): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find signal handler 'add'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

As a complete noob O have no idea what to do next

Comment: Might help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930691/unable-to-connect-signal-and-signal-handler-in-glade-gtk3

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled it with `-rdynamic` flag and solved the problem

```
gcc main.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -rdynamic
```

Comment: @Gerhardh code is still not working but at least the callback functions are now connected which I was asking for.

Comment: @Gerhardh it says `You can accept your own answer in 2 days`